# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Summary’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Tags: r

I am new to r and am taking a basic course in which the identical code below is run without issue but when I try to run it I get the error below.  Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated.

```
polling <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/njm3546/Desktop/xxx/PollingData.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
Summary(polling)
```

Error Message

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Summary’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Comment: `R` is case sensitive. It's `summary`, with lower case `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` is case sensitive and the function you need is `summary` (lowercase s).